# Iteración sobre celdas

Tags: excel, vba

Estoy dando mis primeros pasos en VBA y no puedo lograr una simple iteración con un FOR. Básicamente, lo que estoy intentando hacer es iterar sobre N cantidad de filas y en cada una de esas iteraciones, hacer comparaciones con IF de algunas celdas especificadas de la fila que se esté iterando en ese momento para poner en otra columna de esa misma fila un FALSE o un TRUE.

Tengo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para hacerlo sencillo, la idea sería tener un FOR que recorra las filas 2 y 3, y si la columna G tiene valor 0, ponga un true en ACT_USER (P). Si es 64, que ponga FALSE.

Probe con el siguiente código pero me da error 1004 (incluso sacando el IF que aun no se como definir)

```
Sub USUARIOS_ACTIVOS()



Sheets("Usuarios").Activate
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Obtengo el         número de celdas que estén completadas.
'MsgBox (LastRow)

Dim bloqueo As Integer

For I = 1 To LastRow
    Set bloqueo = ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 7).Value
    If bloqueo = 0 Then
    'aqui debería setear la columma P
    Else
    'aqui debería setear la columma P
    End If
Next I
```

¿Cómo podría hacer esta comparación y cambiar el valor de la columna P, de a una fila por vez?

Gracias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema principal esta en la palabra `Set` de la siguiente linea

```
Set bloqueo = ActiveSheet.Cells(I, 7).Value
```

`Set` se usa para referenciar un objeto a una variable, en este caso no se puede referenciar un objeto a la variable `bloqueo` porque esta es de tipo `integer` y no objeto.

Por otro lado, sugiero que uses `Option Explicit` en cada modulo para forzar a la declaración de variables, también es buena practica que pongas las variables al inicio del código.

Adicionalmente, en este caso el ciclo `for` debe iniciar en 2 en lugar de 1, esto es porque los datos a procesar inician en la fila 2, en la uno están los encabezados de columna.

**Opción 1:** Basado en tu ejemplo, pero con los ajustes indicados antes.

```
Option Explicit

Sub USUARIOS_ACTIVOS()
    Dim LastRow, i As Long
    Dim bloqueo As Integer


    Sheets("Usuarios").Activate
    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'Obtengo el         número de celdas que estén completadas.
    'MsgBox (LastRow)

    For i = 2 To LastRow
        bloqueo = ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 7).Value
        If bloqueo = 0 Then
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8) = True
        Else
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 8) = False
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**Opción 2:** con el ciclo `For Each`

```
Option Explicit

Sub USUARIOS_ACTIVOS2()
    Dim rng, r As Range
    Dim bloqueo As Integer


    Set rng = Sheets("Usuarios").Range("A2", Sheets("Usuarios").Range("A2").CurrentRegion.End(xlDown))

    For Each r In rng
        bloqueo = r.Offset(0, 6).Value
        If bloqueo = 0 Then
            r.Offset(0, 7) = True
        Else
            r.Offset(0, 7) = False
        End If
    Next r
End Sub
```

Comment: Añadir a la respuesta de Nolberto que si trabajas con celdas, el bucle más eficiente y rápido es el `For Each`, el `For i` es mejor para arrays.